# automatic gradient update with tf.py_func()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I know it is possible to update a gradient in the tf.py_func() in tensorflow but the fonction I compute after passing the inputs in the neural nets is a bit complicated...

So I wonder if their is a way for the optimizer to get the gradient automatically from the loss function computed thanks to tf.py_func()?